# I bought a fast, refurbished laptop, but some Windows features are super slow

Tags: windows, windows-10, speed

I've asked Reddit and Quora, but with to prevail. I thought I'd I consult here before I try and talk to Windows tech support or just send it back.

Anyways, here's the situation: I recently bought a refurbished ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo(UX581GV-XB74T) with 32gb of RAM, an RTX 2060, 1 TB SSD, and i7 9th Gen CPU. Pretty decent specs, right?

It's crazy, I can open an application (ex. Davinci Resolve 17, VS Code, Ultimaker Cura) within seconds with no problem. I've ran some pretty heavy codebases with no problems, did some benchmark tests with good results, and even did some video editing and FX effects with ease. Basically, what I'm try to say is running the actually software isn't the problem.

**It's anything Windows related.**

Trying to unzip some of those software application folders took up to 10 minutes, my Microsoft Store takes 5 to 10 minutes and doesn't work half the time, trying to get a startup application(like the Terms & Conditions, Directory Location, etc.) for any given software takes forever before I actually see the window, and sometimes even the search bar in the lower left freezes up.

I've watched some YouTube videos on how to speed up windows but with little results. If anyone has any idea on why some of these features are so slow, please let me know. If you need any more details, I'll be active. I'll try Windows Tech Support but if that's no help I may need to send it back.

Comment: Would doing a fresh install be an option? That's generally what I do with any system I get, especially if I have the option of backing up the factory install.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek like putting a fresh version of Windows on it? It has Windows 10 Pro currently. And how would I do a fresh install?